# Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig' Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.deneme_kaynak">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:label="deneme_kaynak"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:exported="true"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
                android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
                />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

ERROR

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'.

> Error while evaluating property 'namespace' of task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'
> Failed to calculate the value of task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig' property 'namespace'.
> > Failed to calculate the value of property 'namespace'.
> > org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/Users/ddo/Desktop/projects/yedek/deneme_kaynak/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml; lineNumber: 27; columnNumber: 56; Attribute "exported" bound to namespace "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" was already specified for element "activity".

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

flutter run --verbose

```
[        ] > Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[        ] > Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig FAILED
[        ] Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
[        ] You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
[        ] See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
[        ] 26 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 24 up-to-date
[        ] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[   +1 ms] * What went wrong:
[        ] Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'.
[        ] > Error while evaluating property 'namespace' of task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'
[        ]    > Failed to calculate the value of task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig' property 'namespace'.
[        ]       > Failed to calculate the value of property 'namespace'.
[        ]          > org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/Users/ddo/Desktop/projects/yedek/deneme_kaynak/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml; lineNumber: 27; columnNumber: 56; Attribute "exported"
bound to namespace "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" was already specified for element "activity".
[        ] * Try:
[        ] > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
[        ] > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[        ] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
[        ] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[        ] BUILD FAILED in 5s
[ +349 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... (completed in 7.1s)
[+7242 ms] Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
[   +1 ms] "flutter run" took 15,386ms.
[   +3 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:699:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1183:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:281:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:229:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:94:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           
           
[  +70 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 69ms
[        ] Running shutdown hooks
[        ] Shutdown hooks complete
[        ] exiting with code 1
```

tried ./gradlew clean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have  `android:exported="true`" this twice in manifest file please remove one.
[image]

EDIT

You need to add for this element as well

```
<receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver" android:exported="true">
```

its applicable to all services , activity and receiver declared in manifets file : https://cafonsomota.medium.com/android-12-dont-forget-to-set-android-exported-on-your-activities-services-and-receivers-3bee33f37beb

This is how manifest file looks :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.deneme_kaynak">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:label="deneme_kaynak"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:exported="true"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
                android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
                />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
      

        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <receiver#com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

Comment: Please check edited answer @UmutcanBağdu

Comment: can you help me again ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73442994/what-went-wrong-execution-failed-for-task-honeywell-scannercompiledebugjav