# * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':honeywell_scanner:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.deneme_kaynak">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:label="deneme_kaynak"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:exported="true"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
                android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
                />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver" />


        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

symbol:   variable BarcodeReader
location: class HoneywellScannerNative
/Users/ddo/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/honeywell_scanner-3.2.0+13/android/src/main/java/com/plugin/flutter/honeywell_scanner/HoneywellScannerNative.java:108: error: cannot find symbol
properties.put(BarcodeReader.PROPERTY_UPC_E_ENABLED, true);
^
symbol:   variable BarcodeReader
location: class HoneywellScannerNative
Note: /Users/ddo/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/honeywell_scanner-3.2.0+13/android/src/main/java/com/plugin/flutter/honeywell_scanner/HoneywellScannerPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
37 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':honeywell_scanner:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

app/build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.deneme_kaynak"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 29
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

EDIT:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve project :honeywell.
> Required by:
> project :app > project :honeywell_scanner
> > No matching configuration of project :honeywell was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a component, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.2.2', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but:
> - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

Comment: Please upgrade you lib  honeywell_scanner to latest one

Comment: help me please!

Comment: Run this command in your terminal 
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps to integrate properly   `honeywell_scanner`

https://pub.dev/packages/honeywell_scanner

1. flutter pub add honeywell_scanner

2.Copy the honeywell folder which is inside the example code sources at:

.../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/honeywell_scanner-x.x.x+x/example/android/honeywell

into your android project module which is going to use this plugin. This step is necessary and crucial because the Honeywell Data Collection Android library is a bundle .aar which has to be referenced as a project library.

3. Add this include ':honeywell' to your settings.gradle in your android project module to allow the plugin to locate the honeywell.aar library.
4. Add tools:replace="android:label" under application tag in your AndroidManifest.xml, this is required because the honeywell.aar library defines an android:label="@string/app_name" which conflicts with your project's label resulting in a Manifest merger failed error